# mysterious conversion in pandas dataframe, how to disable that

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code looking like this:

```
        series_tmp = pd.Series()
        series_tmp["date"] = pd.Timestamp(str(msg.date))
        series_tmp["Timestamp_downloaded"] = pd.Timestamp.now(self._timezone_to_use)
        series_tmp["contract_str"] = contract_str_now
        series_tmp["open"] = float(msg.open)
        series_tmp["high"] = float(msg.high)
        series_tmp["low"] = float(msg.low)
        series_tmp["close"] = float(msg.close)
        series_tmp["volume"] = float(msg.volume)
        series_tmp["count"] = float(msg.count)
        series_tmp["WAP"] = float(msg.WAP)
        series_tmp["hasGaps"] = float(msg.hasGaps)
        # print series_tmp
        self._df_to_record_historical_data = self._df_to_record_historical_data.append(pd.Series(series_tmp),ignore_index=True)
```

In the end, for some reason, the date type data for the final dataframe has become some nonsense like:

```
date                                              1517270400000000000
Timestamp_downloaded                              1518209472212471000
contract_str            ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)
open                                                           158.74
high                                                           159.18
low                                                            158.73
close                                                          158.91
volume                                                         797602
count                                                           57142
WAP                                                           158.989
hasGaps                                                             0
```

The date has become some number... What's the most easy way to correct that. Note that "`date`" is a time stamp, and the `Timestamp_downloaded` is Timestamp with specified timezone.

**Edit:**
To shed more lights into the problem:

initially by doing:

```
series_tmp = pd.Series()
series_tmp["date"] = pd.Timestamp("20180101")
```

the result is:

```
date   2018-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
In [ ]:
```

By doing:

```
series_tmp = pd.Series()
series_tmp["date"] = pd.Timestamp("20180101")
series_tmp["Timestamp_downloaded"] = pd.Timestamp.now(time_zone_to_use)
```

the timezone information is lost (I actually need to keep it):

```
date                   2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000
Timestamp_downloaded   2018-02-09 21:31:58.566041
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

By doing:

```
series_tmp = pd.Series()
series_tmp["date"] = pd.Timestamp("20180101")
series_tmp["Timestamp_downloaded"] = pd.Timestamp.now(time_zone_to_use)
series_tmp["name"] = "Name1"
```

it becomes:

```
date                    1514764800000000000
Timestamp_downloaded    1518212057225521000
name                                  Name1
dtype: object
```

now, the series cannot store pd.Timestamp it converts it to the integer... This scenario is very difficult for me... Since in the end, I get some dataframe as follow:

```
Timestamp_downloaded    WAP close   contract_str    count   date    hasGaps high    low open    volume
0   1.518212e+18    159.0520    158.71  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   63672.0 1.517184e+18    0.0 159.64  158.66  159.59  957215.0
1   1.518212e+18    158.9895    158.91  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   57142.0 1.517270e+18    0.0 159.18  158.73  158.74  797602.0
2   1.518212e+18    159.0235    158.82  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   60825.0 1.517357e+18    0.0 159.33  158.50  158.96  878128.0
3   1.518212e+18    158.4750    158.60  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   70543.0 1.517443e+18    0.0 158.81  158.15  158.55  1012469.0
4   1.518212e+18    158.0410    157.87  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   67786.0 1.517530e+18    0.0 158.36  157.71  158.17  976233.0
5   1.518212e+18    158.2065    158.09  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   59744.0 1.517789e+18    0.0 159.30  157.62  157.67  825094.0
6   1.518212e+18    158.8200    158.86  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   107830.0    1.517875e+18    0.0 159.24  158.48  158.96  1222665.0
7   1.518212e+18    158.4925    158.23  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   67543.0 1.517962e+18    0.0 158.92  157.92  158.68  895965.0
8   1.518212e+18    157.7935    157.74  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   77263.0 1.518048e+18    0.0 158.23  157.26  157.92  1077249.0
9   1.518212e+18    158.0740    158.01  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   76398.0 1.518134e+18    0.0 158.65  157.70  158.05  866737.0
```

Yet I would need to convert `Timestamp_downloaded` into timezone sensitive pd.Timestamp columns and `date` into timezone **nonsensitive** columns... There is practical reason for me to do this specifically...

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `to_datetime` and not `Timestamp`?

Comment: `1517270400000000000` is not just _"some number"_. It's 01/30/2018 12:00am (UTC).

Comment: I actually want to use Timestamp since all my work flows involves operating with Timestamp.

Comment: Then, that's the timestamp you are looking for.

Comment: @YilunZhang I mean pd.Timestamp~~

Comment: What's the form of your original data looks like, especially for `msg.date`?

Comment: let me edit the question to have more insights. msg.date is something like "20180202"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot solve the problem in the series level. But after i got the corresponding dataframe, I do something like:

```
historical_data_df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(historical_data_df["date"])

historical_data_df["Timestamp_downloaded"] = pd.to_datetime(historical_data_df["Timestamp_downloaded"]).dt.tz_localize(time_zone_to_use)
```

This solves the problem:

```
Timestamp_downloaded    WAP close   contract_str    count   date    hasGaps high    low open    volume
0   2018-02-09 21:53:21.974567936-05:00 159.0520    158.71  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   63672.0 2018-01-29  0.0 159.64  158.66  159.59  957215.0
1   2018-02-09 21:53:21.986366976-05:00 158.9895    158.91  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   57142.0 2018-01-30  0.0 159.18  158.73  158.74  797602.0
2   2018-02-09 21:53:21.998098944-05:00 159.0235    158.82  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   60825.0 2018-01-31  0.0 159.33  158.50  158.96  878128.0
3   2018-02-09 21:53:22.010740992-05:00 158.4750    158.60  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   70543.0 2018-02-01  0.0 158.81  158.15  158.55  1012469.0
4   2018-02-09 21:53:22.022957056-05:00 158.0410    157.87  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   67786.0 2018-02-02  0.0 158.36  157.71  158.17  976233.0
5   2018-02-09 21:53:22.033947904-05:00 158.2065    158.09  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   59744.0 2018-02-05  0.0 159.30  157.62  157.67  825094.0
6   2018-02-09 21:53:22.043888896-05:00 158.8200    158.86  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   107830.0    2018-02-06  0.0 159.24  158.48  158.96  1222665.0
7   2018-02-09 21:53:22.055529984-05:00 158.4925    158.23  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   67543.0 2018-02-07  0.0 158.92  157.92  158.68  895965.0
8   2018-02-09 21:53:22.067960064-05:00 157.7935    157.74  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   77263.0 2018-02-08  0.0 158.23  157.26  157.92  1077249.0
9   2018-02-09 21:53:22.078354944-05:00 158.0740    158.01  ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)   76398.0 2018-02-09  0.0 158.65  157.70  158.05  866737.0
```

More specifically:

extracting the row from this dataframe leads to:

```
Timestamp_downloaded              2018-02-09 17:31:32.948958976-05:00
WAP                                                           158.074
close                                                          158.01
contract_str            ('GBL', 'FUT', 'DTB', 'EUR', '20180308', 0.0)
count                                                           76398
date                                              2018-02-09 00:00:00
hasGaps                                                             0
high                                                           158.65
low                                                             157.7
open                                                           158.05
volume                                                         866737
Name: 9, dtype: object
```

This is the initially desired results asked in the question. It would be great if someone have a method without going this route...